# ValidationAttribute for IEnumerable Property

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have this custom validation attribute for validating a collection.  I need to adapt this to work with IEnumerable.  I tried making the attribute a generic, but you can't have a generic attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class CollectionHasElements : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute 
{
     public override bool IsValid(object value)
     {
         if (value != null && value is IList)
         {
             return ((IList)value).Count > 0;
         }
         return false;
     }
}
```

I'm having trouble casting it to an IEnumerable so that I can check its count() or any().

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `ICollection` type?

Comment: Changing the type is not an option.  The objects are being populated from EF.

Comment: Can you do a cast to `IEnumerable`, ex: `IEnumerable en = value as IEnumerable; if(en != null) { ... }`?

Comment: What problem are you having casting to `IEnumerable`?  `IList` derives from `IEnumerable`, so you should just be able to replace it in your existing code (then change `Count > 0` to `Any()`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```cs
var collection = value as ICollection;
if (collection != null) {
    return collection.Count > 0;
}

var enumerable = value as IEnumerable;
if (enumerable != null) {
    return enumerable.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
}


return false;
```

or, since C# 7.0 with pattern matching:

```cs
if (value is ICollection collection) {
    return collection.Count > 0;
}
if (value is IEnumerable enumerable) {
    return enumerable.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
}
return false;
```

Note: Testing for `ICollection.Count` is more efficient than getting an enumerator and beginning to enumerate the enumerator. Therefore I try to use the `Count` property whenever possible. However, the second test would work alone, since a collection always implements `IEnumerable`.

The inheritance hierarchy goes like this: `IEnumerable > ICollection > IList`. `IList` implements `ICollection` and `ICollection` implements `IEnumerable`. Therefore `IEnumerable` will work for any well designed type of collection or enumeration but not `IList`. For instance `Dictionary<K,V>` does not implement `IList` but `ICollection` and therefore also `IEnumeration`.

---

The .NET naming conventions say that an attribute class name should always end in "Attribute". Therefore your class should be named `CollectionHasElementsAttribute`. When applying the attribute you can drop the "Attribute" part.

```
[CollectionHasElements]
public List<string> Names { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Required Validation Attribute for List and checkbox List

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class CustomListRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var list = value as IEnumerable;
        return list != null && list.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
    }
}
```

If you have checkbox list

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class CustomCheckBoxListRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        bool result = false;

        var list = value as IEnumerable<CheckBoxViewModel>;
        if (list != null && list.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (item.Checked)
                {
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is my View Model

```
public class CheckBoxViewModel
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

Usage

```
[CustomListRequiredAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
public IEnumerable<YourClass> YourClassList { get; set; }

[CustomCheckBoxListRequiredAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
public IEnumerable<CheckBoxViewModel> CheckBoxRequiredList { get; set; }
```